# How to connect the stdin streams of parent and child processes?

Tags: subprocess, stdin, deno

I have problem to write stdin in deno version `1.37.0 (release, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)`. I search in documentation, google, try the code and not work. I found related code in https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7713 but not compatible with the latest version.

I have code like this:

```
// parent.ts
const command = new Deno.Command(Deno.execPath(), {
  args: [
    "run",
    "-A",
    "child.ts"
  ],
  stdout: "piped",
  stdin: "piped"
});

const p = command.spawn();
```

```
// child.ts
const decoder = new TextDecoder();
for await (const chunk of Deno.stdin.readable) {
  const text = decoder.decode(chunk);
  console.log(text);
}

Deno.stdin.close();
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: I'd like to help with this, but you've asked several questions at once: (1) How to write to the `stdin` stream of a child process from the parent? (2) How to connect the `stdin` streams of parent and child processes so that input from a terminal can be handled by the child? (3) How to connect the `stdout` streams of parent and child processes so that output from the child can be seen in the terminal? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77169828/edit) the question to focus on only one? Each SO question should focus on a single problem at a time: see [ask].

Comment: @jsejcksn I've changed it. I think I haven't read the rules regarding how to ask, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect any standard I/O stream of the parent process to a
[child process](https://deno.land/api@v1.37.0?s=Deno.ChildProcess) by using the
value `"inherit"` for the
[option](https://deno.land/api@v1.37.0?s=Deno.CommandOptions) corresponding to
that stream (`stdout`, `stderr`, `stdin`) — for example:

`./parent.ts`:

```ts
const childProcess = new Deno.Command(Deno.execPath(), {
  args: ["run", import.meta.resolve("./child.ts")],
  stderr: "inherit", // Connect stderr of child to stderr of this process
  stdin: "inherit", // Connect stdin of child to stdin of this process
  stdout: "inherit", // Connect stdout of child to stdout of this process
}).spawn();

await childProcess.status;
```

> In fact — when spawning a
> [child process](https://deno.land/api@v1.37.0?s=Deno.ChildProcess) in Deno
> v`1.37.0` — `"inherit"` is the default
> [option](https://deno.land/api@v1.37.0?s=Deno.CommandOptions) value for these
> streams, so you don't **need** to specify it. (But I suggest doing so in case
> the default ever changes — defaults have changed in the past! See
> [denoland/deno#17025](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/17025) and
> [denoland/deno#17334](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/17334).)

So that you can reproduce this example, here's the content of `./child.ts`:

```ts
// Raw mode needs to be enabled for this example — you can read more about it in Deno's API documentation:
Deno.stdin.setRaw(true, { cbreak: true });

for await (
  const str of Deno.stdin.readable.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
) {
  const timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
  console.log(timestamp, str);
}
```

Now, you can run the parent process in your temrinal using this command:

```txt
deno run --allow-read --allow-run=deno parent.ts
```

As you type into (the `stdin` of) your terminal, the data stream will be
forwarded to the child process. The example child module uses
[`console.log`](https://deno.land/api@v1.37.0?s=Console#method_log_12) (which
writes values to `stdout`, followed by a newline). Because the code above also
specified to connect the `stdout` streams of the child and parent processes, you
should see each of your inputs preceded by a timestamp on a new line in your
terminal.

If — for example — you type <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>
<kbd>o</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd> into your terminal, then you'll see output very similar to this:

```txt
2023-09-26T01:03:35.640Z H
2023-09-26T01:03:35.852Z e
2023-09-26T01:03:35.892Z l
2023-09-26T01:03:36.023Z l
2023-09-26T01:03:36.273Z o
2023-09-26T01:03:36.700Z  
2023-09-26T01:03:36.936Z W
2023-09-26T01:03:37.097Z o
2023-09-26T01:03:37.152Z r
2023-09-26T01:03:37.276Z l
2023-09-26T01:03:37.365Z d
```

To stop the Deno parent process, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to send
[the interrupt signal (`SIGINT`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT).

---

In Deno, the standard I/O strems
([`stdout`](https://deno.land/api@v1.37.0?s=Deno.stdout),
[`stderr`](https://deno.land/api@v1.37.0?s=Deno.stderr), and
[`stdin`](https://deno.land/api@v1.37.0?s=Deno.stdin)) each have a corresponding
[`readable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) or
[`writable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream)
property which is an instance of a
[web standard stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API).

> There is a Stack Overflow tag for the topic of those streams: [whatwg-streams-api](/questions/tagged/whatwg-streams-api)

---

To do something such as connecting the parent `stdin` to the child and also
write directly to the child `stdin` in your program code, you'll need to use
additional third-party code to merge those input streams, such as this module in
Deno's `std` library:
[`https://deno.land/std@0.202.0/streams/merge_readable_streams.ts`](https://deno.land/std@0.202.0/streams/merge_readable_streams.ts)